# How to liquidate isolated margin loan on binance spot?

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

I'm unable to find a reliable way to repay my margin loan. I tried calling the [margin-repay endpoint](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#margin-account-repay-margin) but there are cases where I'm getting an error:

```
APIError(code=-3041): Balance is not enough
```

Whenever that happens I'm forced to enter the WebUI and manually click on the button called "Close All Positions" which immediately liquidates all open positions in order to repay my margin loan.

Is there an equivalent API endpoint which immediately kills open positions and repays the margin loan?

Comment: Maybe try looking at the network traffic in Chrome and see what they do when you click that button?

Comment: they call this URL, but it isn't part of the public API https://www.binance.com/bapi/margin/v1/private/isolated-margin/manual-liquidation/BTCUSDT

Comment: Looking for the same thing. That endpoint doesn't work, because it requires login, for the API you use tokens so it's a different authentication system.